# Automatically highlight undefined references

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, highlighting

Is there a way to force LaTeX to automatically change the formatting of the `??` that gets typeset in place of an undefined reference? For example, can one make LaTeX draw a yellow "highlight" background behind the `??`, or render the `??` in red text?

I would like it to be easier to spot these undefined references when skim reading PDF output.

An MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ref{undefinedReference}
\end{document}
```

It would be especially great if this could be made to work for undefined bibliographic citations as well as undefined cross refs.

Comment: Missing references are noted in the log file and produce a warning.  A good start is to keep on eye on what LaTeX tells you there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you will miss this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter

\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries\huge\textcolor{red}{DEFINE #3 NOW, AND MAKE IT QUICK!}}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ref{undefinedReference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A macro that makes the machine punch you in the eye would be missed more frequently than this one.

Comment: Thanks David Carlisle. I used `\nfss@text{\reset@font\colorbox{yellow}{??$_\text{#3}$}}` and put the whole thing into a `.sty` file to make a package that I can invoke to achieve this functionality on all my manuscripts.

Comment: @Ubiquitous I'd prefer the version that punched egreg in the eye, but OK:-)

Comment: How can I adapt this answer for missing citations?

Comment: @Hotschke in principle just copy the definition of `\@citex` from `latex.ltx` and change `\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}` to whatever you want it to be. However more so that `\ref` many citation packages redefine `\@citex` or redefine `\cite` to use some other variant command, so it depends a bit what your current definition is. In any case though the definition will at some point be using a macro that is typesetting a literal `?` and you can simply define it to typeset something else.

Comment: It would be great if there was a package for this, so that we could simply `\usepackage{showundefinedrefs}`, as with for example `\usepackage{showlabels}`.

Comment: @rd11 you could always submit one to ctan

Answer (score 8):

Based on David's answer, here's a solution with PDF annotations as 'yellow "highlight" background':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\makeatletter

\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow,author={RefCheck Assistant}]{??}{DEFINE #3 NOW, AND MAKE IT QUICK!}}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
see \ref{undefinedReference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

without clicking and mouseover you get a tooltip:

[image]