# Automatically change the formatting of undefined autoref

Tags: formatting, autoref

Is there a way to make the "**??**" that show up when a reference (**autoref** in particular) fails to load, **red**? So that it would be also easy to see which references have failed.

I have tried [**this**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176297/automatically-highlight-undefined-references) approach, but it seems to only work for "ref", since the "autoref" uses the "thmtools" package.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I have tried doing these:

```
\usepackage{color}
\def\HyRef@autoref#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \expandafter\HyRef@autosetref\csname r@#2\endcsname{#2}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\def\HyRef@autosetref#1#2#3{% link command, csname, refname
  \HyRef@ShowKeysRef{#2}%
  \ifcase 0\ifx#1\relax 1\fi\ifx#1\Hy@varioref@undefined 1\fi\relax
    \edef\HyRef@thisref{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }%
    \expandafter\HyRef@testreftype\HyRef@thisref.\\%
    \Hy@safe@activesfalse
    #3{%
      \expandafter\@fifthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \HyRef@currentHtag
      \expandafter\@firstoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
      \null
    }%
  \else
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries \textcolor{red}{??}}%
    \@latex@warning{%
      Reference `#2' on page \thepage\space undefined%
    }%
  \fi
}
```

but the color still wouldn't change to **red**.

I am actually a beginner at LaTex so most things are still confusing for me. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Welcome. `\autoref` is part of `hyperref` package: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544301/how-does-autoref-from-the-package-hyperref-know-what-type-of-labels-i-am-re  Copy the definition of `\autoref` and change the line `\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%` to `\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries \textcolor{red}{??}}%`, and use the `xcolor` package for the red, of course. You could even use `???`, or other variations, like `\fbox{???}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Cicada