# how to track undefined references without log notice

Tags: cross-referencing

I have run into a weird situation.  I have a very long book, about 600 pages, with references across chapters.  At the end of the third latex run, I still get an

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Unfortunately, a simple grep for `undef` through the log file comes up empty.  This is quite puzzling.  Is there a way to print out the first undefined reference that seems to be bothering latex??

PS: usually I can isolate errors by just ending the document early and seeing if the error has disappeared, but this is of course not possible in this case...

Comment: Have you tried looking for instances of `??` in the pdf file?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176297/automatically-highlight-undefined-references/176303#176303

Comment: but the only place latex sets the flag to make that wrning at the end it also makes an undefined reference warning in the log (that as you say you can grep for) so something odd is happening if that is missing

Comment: hi mico---actually, the ?? in the pdf file was an idea that was obvious once you mentioned it.  grrr...  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could plant `\show\@refundefined` in various places of your document. After an undefined reference it will change its meaning and so allow you to localize it better:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
zzz

\show\@refundefined

\ref{blub}

\show\@refundefined


\end{document}
```

gives

```
> \@refundefined=\relax.
l.27 \show\@refundefined
                        
? 

LaTeX Warning: Reference `blub' on page 1 undefined on input line 29.

> \@refundefined=macro:
->\@latex@warning@no@line {There were undefined references}.
l.31 \show\@refundefined
```